# When I send a request to an api, I want to see if another api is running at that moment

Tags: c#, .net, post, asp.net-web-api

first of all, I'm new to .Net.
What I want to do is:
To find out if I can reach that API or not when I send a request to another API, using a base web api using .Net and Post method. I would like to see the answer with the Ok() method or another suitable method, I am open to your suggestions on this subject.

```
 public class ApiHealthCheckController : ApiController
{
    List<string> okList = new List<string>() {"True List: "};
    List<string> wrongList = new List<string>() {"Wrong List: "};
    List<string> controllerList = new List<string>()
    {
        "http://localhost/api/Bank/GetBank",
        "http://localhost/api/Bank/CreateBank",
        "http://localhost/api/Bank/FalseBank",//Wrong link
    };
     public List<string> resultCheck(List<string> controllerLinks)
    {
        bool control = true;
        controllerLinks = controllerList;
        foreach(string controllerLink in controllerLinks)
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(controllerLink);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentLength = 0;
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                okList.Add(controllerLink);
                control = true;
                //return Ok(true); 
            }
            else if(response.StatusCode==HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
            {
                control = false;
                wrongList.Add(controllerLink);
            }

        }
        if (control == true)
        {
            return okList;
        }
        else
        {
            return wrongList;
        }
    }
   }
```

and i'm getting this error: System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.'

I was successful when I updated my code as follows. My question now is I want to access my current Api list and then import my working APIs into okList list. I want to take the ones that don't work or those that give any exception errors to a separate wrongList list and show them as a response list. How can I do that.   
Thank You.

Comment: Normally a 405 means that you are using an incorrect request type, try using a GET instead of POST.

Comment: @DmytoHolota Thank you for your opinion. Could you suggest a method where I can use the post method? I prefer the Post method.

Comment: its not about the preferences, if the api method is designed to use a GET request you can't change that (unless you can change the api method to use a post instead of get but that's only works if you are the one who manages the api).

Comment: @DmytoHolota yes you're right i cant change it. But I get this error when I try Get request method:  "The requested resource with API version '1.0' does not support HTTP method 'GET'."  So i should use POST method, right? I'm working at a company, i should figure out this problem

Comment: is there any type of documentation of that api?

Comment: @DmytoHolota I'm sorry, unfortunately no or I don't know. I will be sharing the current codes.

Comment: I updated my post, Can you review? @DmytoHolota

Comment: sorry for the delay, I revised pure edit but can't understand exactly what you want to accomplish, you already are returning the list no?

Comment: @DmytoHolota No problem, thank you for your help. Yes i am returning the list already but what i need is to create a service and make a request to the controller of this api. Where should I write this service outside of the api?

Comment: Yes, you will need to create an request to the api on you're client (web, app, winform). If its a web, you can use javascript to make a request, example: 
https://reqbin.com/code/javascript/wzp2hxwh/javascript-post-request-example

Comment: Thank you for your time, i'm checking out. I think it will be ok.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my last update in function:

```
public List<string> healthCheck(List<string> controllerLinks)
    {
        bool control = true;
        controllerLinks = controllerList;
        HttpWebRequest request;
        HttpWebResponse response;
        foreach (string controllerLink in controllerLinks)
        {
            request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(controllerLink);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentLength = 0;
            try
            {
                response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    okList.Add(controllerLink);
                    control = true;
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                control = false;
                wrongList.Add("Error!: " + ex.Message);
                wrongList.Add(controllerLink);
            }
        }
        if (control == false)
        {
            List<string> add = okList;
            add.AddRange(wrongList);
            return add;
        }
        else { return okList; }
        }
```

So,another question... How can I pull API's from the database and is there a stable method other than pulling them with a link or is this method the right approach? I seek support from experts.   
Thank you so much...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).